# How to select top most <li> element in a hierarchical menu in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I'm implementing a menu bar using jQuery with a nested set of `<ul>` lists, where each `<li>` contains an `<a>` tag.  Given that I can match the specific `<a>` tag via the href attribute, how can I walk the menus so I arrive at the top most enclosing `<li>` element?

I need that so I can set a class="current" which changes the highlighting to reflect the newly selected item.

EDIT: To everyone who responded, thank you.  It was an education, as usual.  I ended up using @PKG's solution... it fit perfectly into my implementation.

Comment: [parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function below will return the top level `<li>` only

```
$(this).parents("li").last();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the click event of the `<a>`, you can use:

`$(this).closest('li')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest("li");
```

If you want the first LI in the entire UL that it is in:

```
$(this).closest("ul").find("li:first");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parents()` like so:

```
var url = window.location.href; // (or however you prefer)

$('a[href*="'+url+'"]').parents('li').addClass('current');
```

Now, how I would do it, would be to add a class to the topmost li, or something, to narrow it down. Otherwise it's going to add the class to all list items in the path, which is also often what you want.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3RX8/1/

Comment: I did something similar to this which @PKG suggested... add a .last() call to .parents('li').  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is vague, I assume you are trying for something like this:

```
// This will loop through all of the ul's on the page and handle the first li
$('ul').each(function(index,element){
    var first_li = $(element).find('li:first');
    // Do something with the li
});
```